# USB Hard Drive still appears in /media after unplugging

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I had a USB hard drive connected a while ago. I couldn't open it - I think it was making a weird clicking noise - so I had to just unplug it. If I remember correctly, I wasn't even able to shut down Ubuntu while the disk was plugged in.

It's still showing up in `/media` weeks later:

[image]

If I try to `umount` it, I get `umount: hard disk: not mounted`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's most likely just an empty folder that had been used as the mounting point.

Open a terminal an run

```
sudo rmdir /media/jack
```

to remove it.